# How can I add tooltip to sfcard cardHeader Title field only?

Tags: css, blazor, syncfusion

Here is my code:

```
<CardHeader Title="@card.Title"  SubTitle=@String.Format("AED {0}" ,@card.Price.ToString())
```

Need to add tooltip to Title field on adding

```
<CardHeader Title="@card.Title" title=@card.Title  SubTitle=@String.Format("AED {0}" ,@card.Price.ToString())
```

on adding getting two parameters are unique and incasesensitive error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are already using Syncfusion controls so why not use the `SfTooltip` as well? You'll need the `Syncfusion.Blazor.Popups` NuGet package if you're not using the generic package that has all the controls.

```
<SfTooltip Content="@card.Title" Position="Position.LeftCenter">
    <CardHeader Title="@card.Title"  SubTitle=@String.Format("AED {0}" ,@card.Price.ToString()) />
</SfTooltip>
```

Comment: Thanks, I already got solution. I added title in div class so tooltip working. This solution is also working for me

Comment: <div title="@card.Title">
    <CardHeader Title="@card.Title"  SubTitle=@String.Format("AED {0}" ,@card.Price.ToString()) />
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement to add tooltip to the Card header title can be achieved by using the SfTooltip control. please check the code below,

**Code snippet:**

```
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Cards
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Popups

<SfTooltip ID="Tooltip" Target=".e-card-header-title" Content="@cardTitle">
  <SfCard ID="HugeImage">
    <CardHeader Title="@cardTitle" SubTitle="Sales Coordinator and Representative" />
</SfCard>
</SfTooltip>

@code{
    public string cardTitle = "Laura Callahan";
}
```

**Tooltip Documentation**: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/tooltip/getting-started

Regards,

Vinitha